# Launching Steam games via command line is very slow on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, steam

**Background**

I have written a small daemon which listens for hotkeys and launches any one of the (currently) six Jackbox Party Pack games. It does this by passing a game id to Steam like so:

```
> Steam.exe steam://rungameid/(jackboxid)
```

It works except it takes 15 - 20 *seconds* to launch a new title, even when Steam is already running.

**My launcher is not the problem.**

At first, I figured the problem was just a bug with my launcher but, upon further investigation, I found that Steam is the cause.

When you use Steam to create a desktop shortcut (right-click the title in the library > Manage > Add desktop shortcut), the resulting shortcut runs the same command.

**Running the game in this fashion is just as slow.**

The Steam.exe process lights up immediately in the Task Manager like it is doing *something*, but I don't know what.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: how long does it take to launch the game from Steam itself?

Comment: It is instantaneous.

Comment: Have you tried using commandline args rather than a URI?

Comment: Did you found solution?